# Executing Rails virtual attribute setters in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model with several virtual attribute setters. I want to build an object but not save it to the database. One setter must execute before the others. How to do?

As a workaround, I build the object in two steps

```
@other_model = @some_model.build_other_model
@other_model.setup(params[:other_model)
```

Where `setup` is:

```
class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def setup(other_params)
     # execute the important_attribute= setter first
    important_attribute = other_params.delete(:important_attribute)

     # set the other attributes in whatever order they occur in the params hash
    other_params.each { |k,v| self.send("#{k}=",v) }
  end
end
```

This seems to work, but looks kludgy. Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

per [neutrino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125805/neutrino)'s suggestion, I added a method to `SomeModel`:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def build_other_model(other_params)
    other_model = OtherModel.new(:some_model=>self)
    other_model.setup(other_params)
    other_model
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good thing that you have this manipulations done in an `OtherModel`'s method, because you can just call this method and not worry about the order of assignments. So I would leave this part but just call it from a `SomeModel`'s method:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def build_other_model(other_params)
    other_model = build_other_model
    other_model.setup(other_params)
    other_model
  end
end
```

So then you would have

```
@other_model = @some_model.build_other_model(params[:other_model])
```

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right road, although calling `build_other_model` from itself didn't work --- using `OtherModel.new(:some_model=>self) did.

Answer (score 0):

I took your idea of deleting the important attribute first in your setup method, but used alias_chain_method instead to make it more of a transparent process:

```
def attributes_with_set_important_attribute_first=(attributes = {})
  # Make sure not to accidentally blank out the important_attribute when none is passed in
  if attributes.symbolize_keys!.include?(:important_attribute)
    self.important_attribute = attributes.delete(:important_attribute)
  end

  self.attributes_without_set_important_attribute_first = attributes
end

alias_method_chain :attributes=, :set_important_attribute_first
```

This way none of your code should change from the normal Rails style

```
@other_model = @some_model.other_models.build(params[:other_model])
```